# dead code warning java

Tags: java, recursion

I have the following part of code:

```
public void deepSearch(File fileToLook,ArrayList<File> fileStorage,DefaultComboBoxModel<String> mod){
        if(fileToLook.isDirectory())
        {
            for(File f:fileToLook.listFiles())
                deepSearch(f,fileStorage,mod);
        }
        else if(fileToLook != null){
            fileStorage.add(fileToLook);
            mod.addElement(fileToLook.getName());
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Reached an end.");
    }
```

But eclipse gives me a dead code warning on this:

```
else
    System.out.println("Reached an end.");
```

Can you explain why this is happening.Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have successfully got to `else if (fileToLook != null)`, then it's guaranteed that it's not `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `fileToLook` can't be null when the `else` statement is reached, since if it is `null`, the first condition will throw a `NullPointerException`.

It would make more sense to refactor the method, and avoid the potential `NullPointerException` :

```
if(fileToLook != null) {
    if(fileToLook.isDirectory()) {
        for(File f:fileToLook.listFiles())
            deepSearch(f,fileStorage,mod);
    } else {
        fileStorage.add(fileToLook);
        mod.addElement(fileToLook.getName());
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Reached an end."); // not sure if you really need this
                                           // statement. It looks like a debug print to me
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to check `fileToLook == null`, so you can keep the nice multi-way `if` structure.

Answer (score 2):

Well the null `if (fileToLook != null)`check is actually not needed, because `if (fileToLook.isDirectory())` already throws a NullPointerException if it is null. The last else can thus never be reached.

Answer (score 2):

The first `if` condition will throw a `NullPointerException` if `fileToLook` is null. The second branch is taken if it's not null. Therefore the third branch is never executed.

You might want to put the null check first.